# How to solve a system of equations with varying exponents?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, fractions

I have 2 equations with two variables $x,y$ that need to be solved. I'm so sure it can be done, but when I try going about it, I hit a wall and just don't know what to do. I also have MATLAB at my disposal, so if anyone has a resource that can solve them with that, that's an option too!

Here's the equations in question:

$$
\dfrac{-2A}{x^{13}}+\dfrac{B}{x^7} + \dfrac{-2A}{(x-y)^{13}}+\dfrac{B}{(x-y)^7}=0    
$$
$$
\dfrac{-2A}{y^{13}}+\dfrac{B}{y^7} + \dfrac{2A}{(x-y)^{13}}+\dfrac{-B}{(x-y)^7}=0 
$$

We assume that $A,B$ are constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found at least one solution.  Suppose that $y=-x$.  Then the two equations reduce to a single equation:

$$
-\frac{2A}{x^{13}}+\frac{B}{x^7}-\frac{2A}{2^{13}x^{13}}+\frac{B}{2^7x^7}=0.
$$
Multiplying by $x^{13}$:
$$
-2A(1+2^{-13})+Bx^6(1+2^{-7})=0.
$$
Hence, $x^6=\frac{2A(1+2^{-13})}{B(1+2^{-7})}$.  This is approximately $2A/B$.

Comment: Nice! In general, i think you can apply a similar approach by assuming that $y = \alpha x$, where $\alpha \ne 1$, but I haven't checked the details.